# Button click changes boolean to true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to make a button that is clicked that changes a boolean(clue1) in a model(clue) to true. I have read that I have to use a form rather than Link_to. I would rather use a link to because I want it to redirect it to another page after it's submitted. From posts online I came up with this:

```
<%= form_for :clue1 do |f| %>
<div><%= f.hidden_field :clue1, :value => true %></div>
<%= f.submit "See Next Clue", class: "btn btn-default"%>
<% end %>
```

But after many attempts I would just get errors. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a form/link like this, you can do this by adding another route and passing no params.  Like this...

Add a route to update this boolean

```
resources :clue do
  patch :update_clue1, on: :member
end
```

Add link_to with method

```
= link_to "Update Clue 1", update_clue1_clue_path(clue), method: :patch
```

and in your controller, add an action

```
def update_clue1
  @clue = Clue.find(params[:id]
  @clue.update_attribute(:clue1, true)
  redirect_to :other_page
end
```

Comment: I am getting this error "`block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `update_clue1' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007fc4ebdf1350> (NameError)" in rake routes when I run rake db:mirgrate.

Comment: Sorry, in routes, they should have been symbols.  My answer was updated.

Comment: I am not sure thanks for your help I have this error it says something is wrong with the controller. `/hunt_controller.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected tIVAR, expecting ')' @clue.update_attribute(:clue1, true) ^`

Comment: That looks like a syntax error in there.  Can you post more of your controller code somewhere?

Comment: Yah I am getting a `ActionController::UrlGenerationError` when I put it all to gether and load the page.

Comment: It also Says `No route matches {:action=>"update_clue1", :controller=>"clue"} missing required keys: [:id]` even though its in the route.rb

Comment: The path method needs a clue parameter (I updated answer).  The reason it's asking for an id is the route expects it and it wasn't passed from the view.

Comment: Thanks for all of the help, I mess around with some stuff and now it just says `Couldn't find Clue with 'id'=Clue`. Now I am really stumped on what to do.

Comment: That means the params[:id] is named 'clue'.  If you have an object, pass that, not that string.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to set a variable with boolean value you can use "remote: true" with link_to tag and create a .js file for that submit action and in that js file you can set the variable value you want.